# Scope of Finagle using

Tags: scala, finagle

I am a newbie in Twitter Finagle. I heard that Finagle is very useful with RPC and microservices in scala. But almost all in twitter doc is related with async http servers (over netty). Explain me scope of using Finagle.

Comment: @Flexo I would like to remove this post, but when i press delete button, i receive message that i can't do it without moderator review. Please, help me remove this (it's not very actual question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As twitter says: `Finagle` is an extensible RPC system for the JVM, used to construct high-concurrency servers.

Finagle is appropriate in the next cases:

- Building high-load microservices, like twitter does
- High performance rpc for jvm languages
- [Finch](https://github.com/finagle/finch) can be used over Finagle for building REST Api in pure functional style